# Coreboot + SeaBios mode switch

Tags: bootstrapping, bios

I was reading some code of Coreboot and the first thing it does is enter in protected mode, this is normal for an intel x86 bootstrapper, afterwards, it loads and call the payload (in this case seabios), seabios does all the necesary initialization procedures for the hardware devices, some of these procedures need to be done in real mode and finally the BIOS call the os bootstraper at 0x7c00 always in real mode.

My question and doubt is: at what point occurs the switch between protected mode and real mode (again)?

Is the final processor mode: big real mode?

Thanks

Comment: Seabios will do the equivalent of a typical 386 class machine with a legacy BIOS. It will put the machine in unreal mode (16-bit) and jump to 0x0000:0x7c00 where it loaded the boot sector of the disk.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question. According to the SeaBIOS execution flow [manual](https://www.seabios.org/Execution_and_code_flow) the last phase of POST is the boot phase. The call to the bootloader starts with call_boot_entry(), which calls farcall16() with argument "0x07c0". farcall16 will call the assembly function transition16 which will switch the cpu back to real mode and will jmp to "0x07c0".

Comment: Actually it starts with the segment as 0x07c0 (when booting from floppy/harddrive). Before the call to `call_boot_entry()` it normalizes the segment to a segment:offset pair. The result is a segment of 0x0000 in `bootseg` and 0x7c00 in `bootip` . By the time the switch to 16-bit real mode (actually unreal mode) is done - the BIOS has far jumped to 0x0000:0x7c00 which is physical address 0x07c00 .

Comment: @MichaelPetch  by saying that the farcall16 has argument 0x07c0 I was trying to simplify things in order to answer on where the transition from 32 to 16 bit takes place. Actually there are many details that i skipped.